# How can we configure credentials of a power bi report using powershell cmdlets

Tags: powershell, powerbi

I have published report on power bi service using powershell cmdlets, but after being published to see the reports i have to provide credentials manually in power bi service.

Right now I am using this API "Data-sets - Update Data-sources In Group" to configure the connections details but in this i have to manually change credentials from power bi service.

NOTE: I'am using direct query to get data for my reports

This is the error I am getting,
[image]